# convert date to timestamp in yii2?

Tags: yii2, timestamp

```
$date = Yii::$app->request->post('date');
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
var_dump($timestamp );
```

> ## error
>
> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>   strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Try var_dump($date), there is probably an array in `date` field in POST data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check you post for an array in `$_POST('date')`

in this case you could access at the value  providing an index

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date[0]);
```